# Yoneda Lemma (again)

Tags: category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma, hom-functor

Let $C^{\wedge} = \text{Fct}(C^{\text{op}}, \text{Set})$.  Let $\text{h}_C : C \to C^{\wedge}, \ X \mapsto \text{Hom}_C(\cdot, X)$.  Then the Yoneda lemma is:

> For $A \in C^{\wedge}$ and $X \in C$, $\text{Hom}_{C^{\wedge}}(\text{h}_C(X), A) \simeq A(X)$.

We have, for $\phi \in \text{Hom}_{C^{\wedge}}(\text{h}_C(X), A)$,

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\text{h}_C(Y, X) @>{\text{h}_C(f, X)}>> \text{h}_C(Z, X)\\
@V{\phi_Y}VV @V\phi_ZVV \\
A(Y) @>{A(f)}>> A(Z)
\end{CD}
\tag{1}
$$

commutes for every $f : Y \to Z$ in $C^{\text{op}}$.  In particular for $Y, Z = X$, associate to $\phi$, $\phi_X(\text{id}_X) \in A(X)$.   Thus our map $\varphi : \text{Hom}_{C^{\wedge}}(\text{h}_C(X), A) \to A(X)$ is given by $\varphi : \phi \mapsto \phi_X(\text{id}_X)$.

---

On the other side, given $s \in A(X)$ we want to associate it to a natural map $\psi(s) \in \text{Hom}_{C^{\wedge}}(\text{h}_C(X), A)$.  That is we want a family of maps $\psi(s)_Y : \text{Hom}_C(Y, X) \to A(Y)$.  By the functoriality of $A$, $A: \text{Hom}_C(Y,X) \to \text{Hom}_{\text{Set}}(A(X), A(Y))$, and composition with $s$ gives a map into $A(Y)$.  Thus $\varphi : s \to A(\cdot)(s)$ hopefully is the inverse map to $\varphi$.

---

$$
\psi \circ \varphi(\phi) = \psi(\phi_X(\text{id}_X)) = A(\cdot)(\phi_X (\text{id}_X))
$$

Given $f \in \text{Hom}_C(Y,X)$ we have $(A(f) \circ \phi_X)(\text{id}_X) = ?$

I'm stuck.

---

Thanks @Sky.

Use this diagram:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\text{h}_C(X, X) @>{\text{h}_C(f, X)}>> \text{h}_C(Y, X)\\
@V{\phi_X}VV @V\phi_YVV \\
A(X) @>{A(f)}>> A(Y)
\end{CD}
\tag{2}
$$

So that $(A(f) \circ \phi_X)(\text{id}_X) = (\phi_Y \circ \text{h}_C(f, X))(\text{id}_X) = \phi_Y \circ f = \text{h}_C(f, X) \circ \phi_Y$

**Still stuck.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]it is just a natural transformation.

Comment: @EyesOnBud yeah

Comment: I see what you're saying use $\text{Hom}_C(X,X) \to \dots$

Comment: @EyesOnBud What is your meaning?Sorry,I do not understand.

Comment: see my edits of OP above.  I'm still not sure...

Comment: @EyesOnBud I see.Because $Hom_C(f,X)(Id_X)=f$.

Comment: Thanks @Sky, I've got it now, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \varphi(\phi) \equiv \phi_X(\text{id}_X) \\
\psi(s)_Y \equiv A(\cdot)(s), \ \forall Y \in \text{Ob}(C)
$$

Then:
$$
\psi\circ \varphi(\phi) = \psi(\phi_X(\text{id}_X))_Y = A(\cdot)(\phi_X(\text{id}_X)) = \phi_Y\circ \text{h}_C(\cdot, X)(\text{id}_X) = \phi_Y (\text{id}_X (\cdot)) = \phi_Y(\cdot) = \phi_Y
$$
since notationally $\phi_Y \equiv \phi_Y(\cdot)$.

The other direction is $\varphi \circ \psi(s) = \psi(s)_X(\text{id}_X) = (A(\cdot)(s))(\text{id}_X) = A(\text{id}_X (s) = \text{id}_{A(X)} (s) = s$.